# how these elements come? - finite field with polynomial $x^2+1$

Tags: field-theory, problem-solving, finite-fields

I am given this finite field. $$K=\mathbb{Z_3}[x]/p$$ with $$p(x)=x^2+1$$

In my textbook, i see that the elements of this field are:
$$\{0, 1, 2, x, x +1, x+2, 2x, 2x + 1, 2x + 2\}$$

I dont understand how these come. I know that $0, 1, 2$ are elements of $\mathbb{Z_3}$, but where is $x+$ is coming from?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ is the set of all polynomials with coefficients from $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $K$ is the set of all possible remainders when dividing those polynomials by $p$.

Comment: @njguliyev, thanks but i dont understand the word "all polynomials". do they have to have certain degree? because there are A LOT OF polynomials out there to take

Comment: No, $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ contains polynomials of all degrees, but after dividing by $p$ there remains only finite number of possible cases.

Comment: @njguliyev, can you please give a small step where i can see how you calculate the $x+1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$ is the set of all polynomials whose coefficients are elements of $\Bbb{Z}_3$. So this includes things like $0$, $x + 1$, $x^2 + 2x + 1$, $x^{100}$, and so on. When we take the quotient, we're essentially dividing all these polynomials by $x^2 + 1$ and considering elements to be the same as their remainders. So the elements of the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]$ are precisely the polynomials which are remainders upon division by $x^2 + 1$.

So the polynomial $x$, when divided by $x^2 + 1$ looks like

$$x = 0(x^2 + 1) + x$$

So $x$ is a remainder, and so appears in the list. On the other hand,

$$x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 1 = (x + 2)(x^2 + 1) + x + 2$$

So we see that $x + 1$ is a remainder as well, and must appear on our list (more directly, $x^2 + 1$ is its own remainder upon division).

---

Note that if $f$ is any polynomial, then $f/(x^2 + 1)$ will have a remainder which is either constant or degree $1$, so the quotient ring will actually be quite small (prove this!).

Comment: thanks, but i still dont understand the fact that if i continue this division, will i get many elements or is there limit where i cannot divide anymore?.. i mean, why in my textbook there are only 9 elements?

Comment: @doniyor Take any polynomial and divide by $x^2 + 1$, writing it in the quotient-remainder form. What possible forms can the remainder have?

Comment: ok, but how comes that in my textbook field has 9 elements?

Comment: @doniyor Just count how many polynomials there are of degree $1$ or $2$, or are constant.

Comment: thanks, but we take only polynomials of degree $0$ and $1$, right?

Comment: @doniyor Yes, sorry. I meant degree $1$ and constant only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10805/discussion-between-doniyor-and-t-bongers)

Comment: great help! better help than my professor's :)